# F# Function Type Annotation for Multiple Types

Tags: generics, f#, functional-programming

I'm trying to define a "quasi-generic" function.  Rather than making it entirely generic, I'd like it to work only for the "integer" types (i.e. byte, sbyte, int16, uint16, int, uint32, int64, uint64, bigint).

How can I put this into a type annotation on the function definition?  To clarify, how would I rewrite the following code to actually work (using only 3 types presumably without loss of generalization):

```
let square (x: int|int64|bigint) =
    x * x
```

Comment: This might be achievable with [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints) - whether or not it'd be easy/practical however, I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, there is no way to resolve such a type constraint using standard .NET generics at runtime.

F# does allow you to express a limited form of such constraints by resolving them at compile time and inserting the proper function call inline.  This makes use of [statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters).

It's quite simple for the case you have described, you can just write:

```
let inline square x = x * x
```

This will work for any type `'T` which has the `*` operator defined.

You can also apply specific static/member constraints explicitly but this requires more ugly syntax, e.g.

```
let inline id item =
    ( ^T : (member Id : int) (item))
```

This example function will operate on any type that exposes an `Id` property of type `int`.

---

**Update:** Based on the specific use case you're describing, you really type-classes.  Those don't really exist in F# (aside from a few hard-coded examples) but you can simulate them using a marker type and member constraints, here is an example:

```
type Marker =
    |Marker

    static member Multiply (marker : Marker, numX : int, numY : int) =
        numX * numY
    static member Multiply (marker : Marker, numX : int64, numY : int64) =
        numX * numY

let inline multiply x y =
    ((^T or ^U) : (static member Multiply : ^T * ^U * ^U -> ^S) (Marker, x, y))

multiply 5 7
multiply 5L 7L
```

Notice this lets you specify the exact types you want to allow the functionality on.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to square numbers, I just thought it would be an easy example.  I'm trying to create some functions that perform primality testing and specific factorization techniques.  I don't want to allow these functions to work on floats because factorization wouldn't make any sense and some of the algorithms would go haywire.

Comment: @Talmage Is the updated answer more what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this was actually the approach I was thinking about as I was eating lunch.  I'll try to fully digest the responses tonight and then mark the question answered.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically 3 approaches to your problem

**a) the types you are using already support the operators/methods you want to apply to them**
In this case simply add `inline` in front of your function and be happy

**b) you have full control over the types you are using**
That is you can define new members at the function definition without using extension methods. In this case you define a method on each class implementing what you need

```
type MyInt16 = MyInt16 of int
    with
    static member Mult(x, y) = 
        match x,y with
        | MyInt16 x', MyInt16 y' -> MyInt16 (x' * y')

type MyInt32 = MyInt32 of int
    with
    static member Mult(x, y) = 
        match x,y with
        | MyInt32 x', MyInt32 y' -> MyInt32 (x' * y')
```

and an inline function using generic type constraints with this rather weird looking syntax

```
let inline mult (x:^T) (y:^T) = (^T : (static member Mult: ^T -> ^T -> ^T) (x, y))
```

And then you Test

```
let a = MyInt16 2
let b = MyInt16 3

let c = mult a b
```

This works. Lets see what happens when we use different types

```
let d = mult a (MyInt32 3)
```

The above will get you an error.

**c) you don't have full control over your types**
That is you can't define methods within the type but you would have to use extension methods. The problem with extension methods is that they can't be used
with inline functions using generic type constraints. In this case you better fall back to the [parameter approach I described here](https://robkuz.github.io/Explicit-vs-Implicit/)

```
type MultParam =
    | MyInt16Param of System.Int16
    | MyInt32Param of System.Int32
with 
    static member op_Implicit(x: System.Int16) = MyInt16Param x
    static member op_Implicit(x: System.Int32) = MyInt32Param x
```

Then define again an inline function with generic constraints that converts your incoming type into your wrapper type

```
let inline (!>) (x:^a) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> ^b) x)
```

and add your implementation. This time a bit wordier as we need to use pattern matching

```
let inline mult' (x: ^T) (y: ^T) : ^T =
    let x' = !> x
    let y' = !> y 
    let r = 
        match x', y' with
        | MyInt16Param x'', MyInt16Param y'' -> x'' * y'' |> box
        | MyInt32Param x'', MyInt32Param y'' -> x'' * y'' |> box
        | _ -> failwith "Not possible"
    r :?> _
```

Now let's test again

```
let e = mult' (int16(2)) (int16(3))
```

This works. Lets see what happens when we use different types

```
let f = mult' (int16(2)) (int32(3))
```

Error again as it should be.

Option b) is basically an emulation of Haskells type class feature where as
option c) is closer to OCamls polymorphic variants

Answer (score 1):

Constraints, shorthand for the combined effects of two features of the F# type system ([Statically Resolved Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) and Member [Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints)), may help. Their employment allows exclusion of incompatible types at compile time, albeit with multiple, verbose error messages.

```
module MyInt =
    type MyInt<'T> = private MyInt of 'T
    type Wrap = Wrap with
        static member ($) (Wrap, value : int   ) = MyInt value
        static member ($) (Wrap, value : int64 ) = MyInt value
        static member ($) (Wrap, value : bigint) = MyInt value
    let inline create value : MyInt<_> = Wrap $ value

let x = MyInt.create 1 // MyInt.MyInt<int>
let y = MyInt.create 1I // MyInt.MyInt<bigint>
let z = MyInt.create 1.0 // Error  No overloads match for method 'op_Dollar'. ...
```

If it's inconvenient to attach constraints on entry to the specialized domain, this can also be done when leaving.

```
module MyInt' =
    type MyInt<'T> = private MyInt of 'T
    type Unwrap = Unwrap with
        static member ($) (Unwrap, MyInt(value : int   )) = value
        static member ($) (Unwrap, MyInt(value : int64 )) = value
        static member ($) (Unwrap, MyInt(value : bigint)) = value
    let inline myInt value = Unwrap $ value
    let x, y, z = MyInt 1, MyInt 1I, MyInt 1.0

let a = MyInt'.myInt MyInt'.x // int
let b = MyInt'.myInt MyInt'.y // bigint
let c = MyInt'.myInt MyInt'.z // Error  No overloads match for method 'op_Dollar'. ...
```